# Having errors in installing yeoman

Tags: angularjs, npm, homebrew, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

having this error.. 
I have installed node using brew.
Trying to setup a angular project but by running commands dependencies folders are not getting created and giving this error.

```
- node-libs-browser node_modules/webpack/node_modules/node-libs-browser
- watchpack node_modules/webpack/node_modules/watchpack
- chokidar node_modules/webpack/node_modules/watchpack/node_modules/chokidar
npm ERR! Darwin 14.1.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/6.3.1/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "--save-dev" "webpack@^1.4.0"
npm ERR! node v6.3.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! path /Users/temp/Desktop/node_modules/webpack
npm ERR! code ENOTEMPTY
npm ERR! errno -66
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rename '/Users/temp/Desktop/node_modules/webpack' -> '/Users/temp/Desktop/node_modules/.webpack.DELETE'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/temp/Desktop/faltu/npm-debug.log
```

how to solve this?

Comment: What you have tried? which command give ?

Comment: I am trying to simply trying to run a simple project which is given by yeoman generator by fountain webapp. So I tried yo -v . I got some option like what I needed for eg, sass/css, angular1, angular2 etc..After all these steps I am having this error and there is no folder which is getting created

Answer (score 0):

**Project Setup (yeoman gulp Angular)**

Install node (https://nodejs.org/en/)

```
Update npm

npm install npm -g
```

Install yo, gulp, and bower

```
npm install -g yo

npm install -g gulp

npm install -g bower
```

Install generator-gulp-angular

```
npm install -g generator-gulp-angular
```

Create a new project folder and open command line or terminal in that folder.
Run the yo generator to create project structure and answer the questions that follow

```
yo gulp-angular [app-name]
```